# when use this library :----- react-native-tesseract-ocr

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

D:\OCR2>npm run android

> OCR2@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\OCR2\node_modules\react-native-tesseract-ocr\android\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\OCR2\node_modules\react-native-tesseract-ocr\android\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

```
at makeError (D:\OCR2\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\OCR2\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\OCR2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\OCR2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

D:\OCR2> npm i rn-text-detector --save

added 1 package, and audited 974 packages in 3s

102 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

D:\OCR2>npm run android --warning-mode=all

> OCR2@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\OCR2\node_modules\react-native-tesseract-ocr\android\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\OCR2\node_modules\react-native-tesseract-ocr\android\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

```
at makeError (D:\OCR2\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\OCR2\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\OCR2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\OCR2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

D:\OCR2>

Answer (score 0):

******i found a soluation******

**android/build.gradle**

```
 ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
                 kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"   //use this line -----------

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
```